# How to compare the values from a dictionary and list through iteration

Tags: python, list, dictionary, for-loop, iterator

I am trying to compare the value of each key from a dictionary to each value within a list. Unfortunately, I cannot figure out a way to do that, since in the second for loop, the variable "column" is a string key, and I want to iterate through both the same number of instances in my "row" list as there is columns. Lists can only take integers, and I don't think dictionaries can take integers to iterate.  How can I write this, to be able to iterate through both the dictionary and list to compare.

The size of the list is the same as the size of the dictionary, in terms of instances within them.

```
for row in data:
    for column in dna:
        if dna[column] != int(row['?????']):
            break
    else:
        print(row[0])
        break
else:
    print("No match")
```

Comment: update your post with sample input and expected output

Answer (score 0):

The builtin function [`zip`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#zip) can be used to iterate in parallel over multiple iterables. You can achieve the desired result using it as follows:

```
for dict_key, list_item in zip(my_dict, my_list):
    # your code here
```

Answer (score 0):

In order to get acces to the keys and values, you should use:

```
for key, value in your_dictionary.items():
    #your code here
```

when you use `your_dictionary.items()` what you got is access to an iterable that looks like `dict_items([(key1,value1), (key2, value2), ...])`